# Passing updated values from Child Component to Parent Component

Tags: reactjs

I am difficulty with a Child component in my React app which has a form containing updated values that I would like to pass back to the parent so that the state can be updated.  However when trying to updated a value in child component the value does not change and I get the following error...

```
 Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `TextInput`.
```

I have a parent component

```
export default class Patient extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   autoBind(this);
   ...
   this.onOverviewChange = this.onOverviewChange.bind(this);
 }

onOverviewChange(event) {
   this.setState({[this.state.PATIENT[0].FName]: event.target.value});
  }

render() {
...
  <OverviewWrapper onchange={this.onOverviewChange} overview={this.state.PATIENT} ovtype={this.state.COMPPROPS} />
...
}
```

Overview Wrapper component determines if the panel will appear as read-only or editable...

```
 export default class OverviewWrapper extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }

render() {

    const overview = this.props.overview;
    const type = this.props.compState;

    let OverviewWrapper = null
    switch (type) {
        case "Edit" : 
            OverviewWrapper = OverviewEditPane
            break
        default: 
            OverviewWrapper = OverviewPane
            break
    }

    return <OverviewWrapper {...this.props}  />
}
}
```

Then I have my editable component where I'm trying to allow the user to change values.

```
export default class OverviewEditPane extends React.Component {  

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  autoBind(this);

}

render () {
  return (
          <table>
            <FormFields>
                <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.overview.map((P) => {return <TextInput size='small'  key={P.id} id={P.id} value={P.FName} onChange={P.onOverviewChange}  />;})}</td>
                </tr>
```

Patient Data JSON

```
"PATIENT": [{
    "id": 6,
    "FName": "Chris",
    "LName": "Baker",
    "Height": "62",
    "Weight": 320,
    "DOB": "1988-09-18T00:00:00",
    "Active": true
  }]
```

Comment: could you post the code for TextInput  component and FormFields component?

Comment: How does your state look like in `Patient` ?

Comment: TextInput and FormFields both are part of the Grommet design system for React. http://grommet.io/docs/form-field and http://grommet.io/docs/text-input

Comment: @SrThompson posted the state of PATIENT into the post.

Comment: @divine TextInput and FormFields both are part of the Grommet design system for React. grommet.io/docs/form-field and grommet.io/docs/text-input

Comment: thank you both for your guidance.

Comment: @jgoraya on <TextInput ... /> you are passing onChange property. replace it with onDOMChange and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs. First, you're using `onChange`, but your grommet components takes a `onDOMChange` prop instead. The callback you're passing to `onChange` is also wrong, you're trying to take `onOverviewChange` from the `patient` object instead of using it from `OverviewEditPane`'s props. Finally, your state updater is incorrect. Try these fixes:

```
class OverviewEditPane extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { overview, onchange } = this.props;
    return (
      overview.map(
        (patient) =>
          <TextInput
            size='small'
            key={patient.id}
            id={patient.id}
            name={patient.id}
            value={patient.FName}
            onDOMChange={onchange} />
      )
    )
  }
}

class OverviewWrapper extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <OverviewEditPane {...this.props} />
  }
}

class Patient extends React.Component {
  state = {
    PATIENT: [{
      id: 6,
      FName: "Chris",
      LName: "Baker",
      Height: "62",
      Weight: 320,
      DOB: "1988-09-18T00:00:00",
      Active: true
    }]
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onOverviewChange = this.onOverviewChange.bind(this);
  }

  onOverviewChange(event) {
    const { target: { value, id } } = event;
    this.setState(prevstate => ({
      PATIENT: prevstate.PATIENT.map(p => {
        if (p.id === parseInt(id, 10)) {
          p.FName = value;
        }
        return p;
      })
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OverviewWrapper onchange={this.onOverviewChange} overview={this.state.PATIENT} ovtype={this.state.COMPPROPS} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Also my apologies for the late recognition.

Comment: @jgoraya I'm glad I could help :)